# Some of NodeJS HTTP connection to Apache Solr got error ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, http, solr

I have this simple nodejs script and I run simply by `node test.js`;

```
const http = require('http');

let URL = "http://solrserver:8983/solr/some-collection/select?wt=json&q=*:*&rows=5"

http.get(URL, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

If I run the script, then it runs just ok, output is something like this

```
{
  responseHeader: { status: 0, QTime: 0, params: { q: '*:*', rows: '5', wt: 'json' } },
  response: {
    numFound: 2133,
    start: 0,
    docs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Here is the problem:
Once I increase the url param `rows=6`, it return response on `end`, and also there is `error`.

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
{
  responseHeader: { status: 0, QTime: 0, params: { q: '*:*', rows: '6', wt: 'json' } },
  response: {
    numFound: 2133,
    start: 0,
    docs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

What could be the issue ? I stuck, some guide to right direction will be much appreciated.

But if I try using curl

```
curl http://solrserver:8983/solr/some-collection/select?wt=json&q=*:*&rows=6
```

It runs just fine

Comment: do you have access to solr admin page like http://serverIp:port/solr/#/collectionName/query

Comment: yes I have @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: There do you see the data properly when you query to the same collection from solr admin page

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti, yes, it run just fine from admin. I think its problem with nodejs http client and the Solr server,  but I don't know  what it is